# What does a module's manifest directive RequiredAssemblies do behind the scenes?

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, powershell-module

I have this simple (test-)module with the following manifest file (`t\t.psd1`):

```
@{
   ModuleVersion         = '0.0.1'
   RequiredAssemblies    = 'Oracle.DataAccess'
}
```

The corresponding module file (`t\t.psm1`) is equally simple:

```
function t {}
```

After importing the module, I can use the functionality of the `Oracle.DataAccess` assembly, as expected.

*However*, if I start a new PowerShell session and execute

```
add-type -assemblyName Oracle.DataAccess
```

I receive the error message *add-type -assemblyName Oracle.DataAccess*, which surprises me because I thought that the `RequiredAssemblies` directive in the manifest file essentially executes the same command.

Apparently, my assumption was wrong. So, what does this directive really do and why does it find the assembly, but `add-type` does not?